# RxJS ordering an async firebase observable stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

I am building a database app in Angular and am using Firebase as a backend.

In the first case I have two collections in firebase: **groups** and **users**. Groups has a bunch of documents which have a name string (i.e. StackOverflow Members Group), and an array of references to users who manage the group. Those references are to be used to cross-reference the 'users' collection, where the document id is the same as the referenceid.

[image]

So the way this is dealt with is:

- Groups is queried to get a list of the groups the current user is a
  manager of.
- This returns the names of the groups but also the IDs of
  all the people who can manage the course.
- These IDs are then used to
  query the users collection and get a name and email for that
  person/manager.

What I am struggling with is getting the synchronisation right with RxJS. My main function to call this looks like:

```js
export interface Group {
    name: string; managers: {name: string, email: string, uid: string}[]
}

export class ClassesComponent implements OnInit {

    groups: Group[];
    user: User;

    constructor(private db: DatabaseService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const groups = this.getAllGroups();

        groups.subscribe(() => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.groups));
        })
    }

    getAllGroups(): Observable<any> {
        let newListOfGroups: Group[] = [];

        return this.getGroups().pipe(map((groups: QuerySnapshot<any>) => {
            groups.forEach((group: QueryDocumentSnapshot<any>) => {
                
                // define the variables for the groups
                let newGroup: Group = {name: group.data().name, managers: null};
                let groupManagers: {name: string, email: string, uid: string}[] = [];

                // create the empty array for the observables for each user query
                let obsArray: Observable<any>[] = [];

                // for each user reference get an observable reference to the data
                group.data().managers.forEach(user => {
                    obsArray.push(this.getUserName(user.id));
                });

                // use concat to execute all subscriptions at once
                concat(obsArray).subscribe(data => {
                    // log the output of the observable 
                    console.log(data);
                });

                // add these values to the group variables
                newGroup.managers = groupManagers;
                newListOfGroups.push(newGroup);
            })
            
            // make the groups list the global list and repopulate the screen
            this.groups = newListOfGroups;

        }, (error: any) => {
            // standard error...
            console.log(`Error loading groups: ${error.message}`);
        }));
    }

    // these two functions are normally in a service but put here for simplicity.

    getGroups(): Observable<QuerySnapshot<any>> {
        const userId = this.user.id;
        return this.firebase.collection('group', grp => grp.where('managers', 'array-contains', this.firebase.collection('users').doc(userId).ref)).get();
    }

    getUserName(uid: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.firebase.collection('users').doc(uid).get().pipe(take(1), map((data: DocumentSnapshot<any>) => {
            return {name: data.data().name, email: data.data().email, id: uid};
        }));
    }

}
```

The output of the groups are fine, but the manager data from **getUserName** where I want an array returned is returning an observable and obviously its all out of sync because the user queries are done asynchronously inside a synchronous pattern.

I'm struggling to work out what I need to do to have this all run asynchronously and then come back together so its in the structure that I want.

Answer (score 1):

I mimiced your types as I haven't worked with firebase, but I think I got decently close.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-demo-s7m1mc?file=index.ts

```
import { of, forkJoin, Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, map, mergeAll, mergeMap, tap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';
// Made up some fake types
interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  uid: string;
}

type InCompleteGroup = {
  data: () => { name: string; managers: { uid: string }[] };
};
// End of fake types

const randomResponseDelay = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;

function getGroups(): Observable<Partial<InCompleteGroup>[]> {
  return of([
    {
      data: () => ({ name: 'g1', managers: [{ uid: '111' }, { uid: '333' }] })
    },
    {
      data: () => ({ name: 'g2', managers: [{ uid: '222' }] })
    }
  ]).pipe(delay(randomResponseDelay()));
}

function getUserName(uid: string): Observable<string> {
  return of(`Mr Smith ${uid}`).pipe(delay(randomResponseDelay()));
}

function getAllGroups() {
  return getGroups().pipe(
    mergeAll(), // split groups into single group emits
    mergeMap(group => {
      const namedManagersInGroup$ = forkJoin(
        group.data().managers.map(userManager =>
          getUserName(userManager.uid).pipe(
            tap(x =>
              console.log('getUserName done for user with uid', userManager.uid)
            ),
            map(userName => ({ ...userManager, name: userName }))
          )
        )
      );
      return namedManagersInGroup$.pipe(
        map(managersOfGroup => ({
          name: group.data().name,
          managers: managersOfGroup
        }))
      );
    }),
    toArray() // glue back together to an array
  );
}

getAllGroups().subscribe(all => console.log('done', all));
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks so much. I get how this works for the most part after some line by line work - VSC doesn't accept 'mergeAll()' in that position though, with the error: TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. Im not sure why because form the docs mergeAll should provide an Observable...

Comment: Maybe it's related to the rxjs version used, my stackblitz uses the latest available. Or if there's a mixup of imports, like if importing a static instead of an operator. I'm just guessing, would need more details to help further :)

Comment: RxJS is 7.1.0 and I did check initially it wasnt static and seems to be the imported from rxjs version.

It seems to be a typeerror, when I change the types to any it still fails though...

Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<ObservableInput<unknown>, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<QuerySnapshot<any>, unknown>'.
      Type 'ObservableInput<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'QuerySnapshot<any>'.
        Type 'PromiseLike<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'QuerySnapshot<any>': docs, query, metadata, size, and 4 more.

Comment: So its something to do with the type of observable being passed - so i think I just need to go through the observable chain to work this out :/